# after insert trigger in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can we create **after insert** trigger on indexed view in sql server.

I am creating a after insert trigger in sql server on indexed view.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv 
ON STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv
AFTER INSERT AS

BEGIN

DECLARE

@count_rec int,

@new_poor INT,
@new_average INT,
@new_excellent INT,
@new_stud_num VARCHAR(10), 
@new_mem_set INT, 
@new_lname VARCHAR(25), 
@new_fname VARCHAR(25), 
@new_report_date date, 
@new_total_certs INT


select @new_stud_num=stud_num, @new_mem_set=mem_set, @new_lname=lname, @new_fname=fname, @new_report_date=report_date, @new_total_certs=total_certs from inserted;


select @count_rec = count (*) from fuzzy_param_trapezoid where MEM_SET = (select mem_set from inserted);
--dbms_output.put_line(count_rec);
if(@count_rec = 0)

begin --if

--update fuzzy attributes of stud_fuzzy_orders_mv
SET @new_poor =  dbo.FIT.update_certs_poor(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set);
SET @new_average = dbo.FIT.update_certs_average(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set);
SET @new_excellent = dbo.FIT.update_certs_excellent(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set);

INSERT INTO STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS values(@new_stud_num, 
@new_mem_set,
@new_lname, 
@new_fname,
@new_report_date, 
@new_total_certs, dbo.FIT.update_certs_poor(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set),
dbo.FIT.update_certs_average(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set), 
dbo.FIT.update_certs_excellent(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set));

UPDATE STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv set POOR=@new_poor, AVERAGE=@new_average, EXCELLENT=@new_excellent where stud_num=@new_stud_num and mem_set=@new_mem_set;

end;--end if

END;

GO
```

I am getting the below error

```
Msg 8197, Level 16, State 6, Procedure t_STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv, Line 1
The object 'STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.
```

and I am running on the correct database only, the object STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv is existing in the database.

Comment: This trigger is broken. It assumes `inserted` contains exactly one row, which is *not* a safe assumption. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows, and triggers should be written to deal with this (ideally by joining `inserted` to other tables to create a *set* based change).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating trigger against `View` instead of `table`.

You might want to insert data to columns not visible in the view. To do so, create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view to handle inserts.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv ON STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count_rec int,@new_poor INT,@new_average INT,@new_excellent INT,@new_stud_num VARCHAR(10),@new_mem_set INT, 
            @new_lname VARCHAR(25),@new_fname VARCHAR(25),@new_report_date date,@new_total_certs INT

    SELECT @new_stud_num=stud_num, @new_mem_set=mem_set, @new_lname=lname, @new_fname=fname, @new_report_date=report_date, @new_total_certs=total_certs 
    FROM inserted;

    SELECT @count_rec = COUNT (*) FROM fuzzy_param_trapezoid WHERE MEM_SET = (SELECT mem_set FROM inserted);
    --dbms_output.put_line(count_rec);

    IF(@count_rec = 0)
    BEGIN --if
        --update fuzzy attributes of stud_fuzzy_orders_mv
        SET @new_poor =  dbo.FIT.update_certs_poor(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set);
        SET @new_average = dbo.FIT.update_certs_average(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set);
        SET @new_excellent = dbo.FIT.update_certs_excellent(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set);

        INSERT INTO STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS values(@new_stud_num,@new_mem_set,@new_lname,@new_fname,@new_report_date, 
                @new_total_certs, dbo.FIT.update_certs_poor(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set),
                dbo.FIT.update_certs_average(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set), 
                dbo.FIT.update_certs_excellent(@new_stud_num, @new_total_certs, @new_mem_set));

        UPDATE STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv SET POOR=@new_poor, AVERAGE=@new_average, EXCELLENT=@new_excellent 
        WHERE stud_num=@new_stud_num and mem_set=@new_mem_set;

    END;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you. Can u tell me the major difference b/w after and instead of trigger ??

Comment: This answer still contains the worst flaw of the trigger in the question. It assumes `inserted` contains exactly one row. This assumption isn't warranted.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar

after insert- insert  will take place on that table/view first then trigger gets called and trigger body gets executed

instead of insert trigger - trigger gets called and trigger body gets executed only, 
No insert statement gets executed.

But here, I need to insert the row in to indexed view before or after trigger body gets executed.

Instead of insert trigger will not support this directly, so can I write that insert statement in trigger body itself ??

My question here is, will INSERTED table still carry the new values ?? if so I can use them in trigger body.

Comment: @Narendra - views don't *contain* any data. You can't let the insert happen first because there's nowhere for the data to *go*. That's why you *have* to write `INSTEAD OF` triggers against views. Yes, `INSERTED` contains the data that *would* have been inserted into the view, but please also pay attention to my previous comments.